# Using canvas to draw a clock. Query about the save()

Tags: html, canvas, save, clock

I know the function of save() and restore() that they save and restore the current canvas states. But still have no profound understanding of these. When the program call the function to draw the clock, it has cleared all the canvas before redrawing. Why the save() should also be added here. Can anyone explain it? Thanks.

```js
window.onload=function(){

   var oCan=document.getElementById('clock');
   var oCanPen=oCan.getContext('2d');
   drawClock();
   setInterval(function(){
    drawClock();
   },1000);
   function drawClock(){
    // oCanPen.save();
    oCanPen.clearRect(0,0,oCan.width,oCan.height);
    var time=new Date();
    var second=time.getSeconds();
    var minute=time.getMinutes();
    var hour=time.getHours()+minute/60;

   oCanPen.save();

   oCanPen.beginPath();
   oCanPen.arc(200,200,100,0,360*Math.PI/180,false);
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.stroke();

   oCanPen.beginPath();
   for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    oCanPen.moveTo(200,200);
    oCanPen.arc(200,200,100,i*6*Math.PI/180,i*6*Math.PI/180,false);
    }
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.stroke();

   oCanPen.beginPath();
   oCanPen.fillStyle='#fff';
   oCanPen.arc(200,200,90,0,360*Math.PI/180,false);
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.fill();

   oCanPen.beginPath();
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    oCanPen.moveTo(200,200);
    oCanPen.arc(200,200,100,i*30*Math.PI/180,i*30*Math.PI/180,false);
    }
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.stroke();


   oCanPen.beginPath();
   oCanPen.fillStyle='#fff';
   oCanPen.arc(200,200,80,0,360*Math.PI/180,false);
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.fill();
   

   oCanPen.beginPath();
   oCanPen.strokeStyle='red';
   var iSecond=(-90+second*6)*Math.PI/180;
   oCanPen.moveTo(200,200);
   oCanPen.arc(200,200,85,iSecond,iSecond,false);
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.stroke();

   oCanPen.beginPath();
   oCanPen.lineWidth=4;
   oCanPen.strokeStyle='blue';
   var iMinute=(-90+minute*6)*Math.PI/180;
   oCanPen.moveTo(200,200);
   oCanPen.arc(200,200,60,iMinute,iMinute,false);
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.stroke();

   oCanPen.beginPath();
   oCanPen.lineWidth=6;
   var iHour=(-90+hour*30)*Math.PI/180;
   oCanPen.strokeStyle='black';
   oCanPen.moveTo(200,200);
   oCanPen.arc(200,200,40,iHour,iHour,false);
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.stroke();

   oCanPen.restore();
  }

  };
```

```css
 body{
  background: #333;
 }
 canvas{
  background: #f2f2f2;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <title></title>

</head>
<body>

<canvas id="clock" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save and restore are not affected by the content of the bitmap - they simply deal with the state as you say, or "settings" such as color styles, line widths, current font etc.

When you clear the canvas the state remains unchanged. And vica versa, when restoring a state it won't affect any existing content on the canvas.

Typical usage is if you have a state you prefer but need to temporary change things like transformation, styles etc. draw, and then restore so you can get back to what you had without the need of resetting those values.

In your case you can change lineWidth and strokeStyles without worrying about those later.

On the other side, you can avoid save/restore if you are able to keep track of all the state values that changes. This is in many cases faster than save/restore as the latter saves a complete state, not just style and line-width.

In your case you can simply remove save/restore and use this new line of code to avoid it all together:

```
..
var hour=time.getHours()+minute/60;

oCanPen.lineWidth = 1;

oCanPen.beginPath();
..
```

```js
window.onload=function(){

   var oCan=document.getElementById('clock');
   var oCanPen=oCan.getContext('2d');
   drawClock();
   setInterval(function(){
    drawClock();
   },1000);
   function drawClock(){
    // oCanPen.save();
    oCanPen.clearRect(0,0,oCan.width,oCan.height);
    var time=new Date();
    var second=time.getSeconds();
    var minute=time.getMinutes();
    var hour=time.getHours()+minute/60;

            oCanPen.lineWidth = 1;
              
   oCanPen.beginPath();
   oCanPen.arc(200,200,100,0,360*Math.PI/180,false);
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.stroke();

   oCanPen.beginPath();
   for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    oCanPen.moveTo(200,200);
    oCanPen.arc(200,200,100,i*6*Math.PI/180,i*6*Math.PI/180,false);
    }
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.stroke();

   oCanPen.beginPath();
   oCanPen.fillStyle='#fff';
   oCanPen.arc(200,200,90,0,360*Math.PI/180,false);
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.fill();

   oCanPen.beginPath();
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    oCanPen.moveTo(200,200);
    oCanPen.arc(200,200,100,i*30*Math.PI/180,i*30*Math.PI/180,false);
    }
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.stroke();


   oCanPen.beginPath();
   oCanPen.fillStyle='#fff';
   oCanPen.arc(200,200,80,0,360*Math.PI/180,false);
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.fill();
   

   oCanPen.beginPath();
   oCanPen.strokeStyle='red';
   var iSecond=(-90+second*6)*Math.PI/180;
   oCanPen.moveTo(200,200);
   oCanPen.arc(200,200,85,iSecond,iSecond,false);
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.stroke();

   oCanPen.beginPath();
   oCanPen.lineWidth=4;
   oCanPen.strokeStyle='blue';
   var iMinute=(-90+minute*6)*Math.PI/180;
   oCanPen.moveTo(200,200);
   oCanPen.arc(200,200,60,iMinute,iMinute,false);
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.stroke();

   oCanPen.beginPath();
   oCanPen.lineWidth=6;
   var iHour=(-90+hour*30)*Math.PI/180;
   oCanPen.strokeStyle='black';
   oCanPen.moveTo(200,200);
   oCanPen.arc(200,200,40,iHour,iHour,false);
   oCanPen.closePath();
   oCanPen.stroke();

  }

  };
```

```css
body{
  background: #333;
 }
 canvas{
  background: #f2f2f2;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <title></title>

</head>
<body>

<canvas id="clock" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```